# Deserialize an array of json objects from configuration ENV variable in .net core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am currently trying to create a call to ms graph and have the properties passed through to the call that come from an appsettings.json file that I use a configurationBuilder to set as environment variables. This app will also check to see if the columns are present in the table if not it will take the type and create that column. Below is currently just a small example of what the array of objects can look like. How can I deserialize the array of objects because every time I try it ends up null.. Some of the things I have tried are

```
JArray propertiesArray = (JArray)jsonObject["Attr"];
List<(string Name, string Type)> ADproperties = new List<(string, string)>();
foreach (JObject propertyObject in propertiesArray)
{
    string propertyName = propertyObject["Name"].ToString();
    string propertyType = propertyObject["Type"].ToString();
    ADproperties.Add((propertyName, propertyType));
}
```

or

```
/JArray propertiesArray = JArray.Parse(configuration["Attr"]);
            //var ADproperties = (JObject)configuration.GetSection("Attr").GetChildren();
```

```
"Attr": [
    {
      "Name": "id",
      "Type": "nvarchar(255)"
    },
    {
      "Name": "accountEnabled",
      "Type": "nvarchar(255)"
    },
    {
      "Name": "displayName",
      "Type": "nvarchar(255)"
    },
    {
      "Name": "userPrincipalName",
      "Type": "nvarchar(255)"
    }

  ]
```

As mentioned above the array of objects returns null, before I had it that the it was just an array of property names which resulted in what I wanted when I got the children of it..

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you're asking how to deserialize a Json string?

Comment: Your JSON is malformed, it is missing outer braces `{` and `}`.  May we assume they are present?  If so, then your first code sample seems to work perfectly and results in the `List<(string Name, string Type)> ADproperties` getting populated correctly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/O4oAZK.  What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your json string is not valid. You have to fix it by adding { } at  sides. After this you are ready to use this code

```
List<Attr> attrs =  JObject.Parse(json)["Attr"].ToObject<List<Attr>>();
  
public class Attr
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

but if you trying to get data from json config file

```
List<Attr> attr = configuration.GetSection("Attr").Get<List<Attr>>();
```